# How to deploy code on 60 AWS servers from Azure Devops

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, azure-devops

We have multiple servers on AWS and we have repo on Azure Devops. We want to deploy the code from Azure CICD to AWS servers. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: install deployment agents on those and deploy like you normally would?

Comment: We normally deploy from Azure devops we create single pipeline for single server.

Comment: Use deployment group https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what those AWS servers are (EC2 instances, Elastic Beanstalk applications, CodeDeploy-managed instances etc) but be aware there is an extension for Azure DevOps from AWS that enables you to reach AWS services and resources from within your Azure DevOps pipelines - see here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools.

It may help simplify whatever you are trying to reach.

Comment: they are normal ec2 instances.

Comment: If you configure those instances to be part of a CodeDeploy deployment group, you could then use the CodeDeploy task inside the tools I noted to configure and do the work for you without needing to resort to scripting inside your build/release pipeline.

You can find documentation on CodeDeploy [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html).

Comment: Thanks Steve, will try that :)